# JQuery to zebra-stripe tables doesn't work in IE8

Tags: jquery

As my first foray into jQuery, I'm doing a number of things in a webpage generated by PHP. It

1. Highlights items in my Navigation bar in a hover effect
2. Rounds the corners of certain DIVs and
3. Loads a DIV called 'postit' from an external file.
4. It is also meant to zebra-stripe tables with ID='playlist' even if they're in the HTML loaded into the 'postit' DIV.

It all works fine in FF 3.6.10, but the zebra-striping doesn't work in IE8. I adopted a technique found by searching SO and tested it in a stand-alone PHP file with only zebra-striping done by jQuery.

It works there but I think there's some kind of conflict going on between the several things I'm asking jQuery to do in the code below. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Here is some relevant code from the PHP file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/music.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pc-06/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pc-06/jquery.corner.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var jsvar = '<?php echo"$af" ?>';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#top').css('background-color','#934').corner('top keep');
        $('#footer').css('background-color','#934').corner('bottom keep');
        $('#nav a').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('highlighted');
        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
        });
        $('#postit').click(function(){
            $('#postit').animate({
                height: 'toggle'
                },1000, function() {
            });
        });
        $('#postit').load(jsvar).corner('round 10px keep');
        $("#playlist tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
    });
</script>
```

I have a large CSS file, the part related to zebra-striping is

```
#playlist tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color : #ddf;
}

#playlist tr.odd td {
    background-color : #ddf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if jQuery supports nth-child, but it does have :odd, so maybe the following would work better?

```
$("#playlist tr:odd").addClass("odd");
```

Additionally, you can simplify your stylesheet a bit by combining the two selectors down to one so you'll only have to change the value in one place instead of two.

```
#playlist tr:nth-child(odd), 
#playlist tr.odd td {
    background-color : #ddf;
}
```

One last improvement I can suggest is only running the jquery for old versions of IE.  You can use $.support.opacity for that (old versions of IE do have opacity but do it in a non-standard way so will return false).

```
if (!$.support.opacity)
{
    $("#playlist tr:odd").addClass("odd");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but the SO question which gave a workaround for IE's lack of support for `nth-child` said that the selectors have to be separated. I can't find it now, but I know the workaround works for IE8 on my simple standalone page. I don't need to consider versions of IE before IE8, my users are all on a company intranet where IE8 is the minimum

Answer (score 0):

That's because IE8 doesn't support the nth-child pseudo selector well as regards jQuery (there are some issues). You can use jQuery's in built :odd and :even selectors to achieve the same functionality across the board.

```
$("#playlist tr:odd").addClass("odd");
$("#playlist tr:even").addClass("even");
```

Comment: See the comment to @GordonM's answer. I've tried your suggestion, thanks, but it still doesn't work in IE8.